# Why training accuracy is not improving?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm tying to do some image classification training. Just got to work something.
but no matter what neural network I use, still I get no progress. The accuracy is always stuck.

If you can get me any suggestion I will be very glad. I already tried to tweak batch size, etc...

You can find all the data and content here: https://github.com/marcusdiy/testai

```
Train for 31 steps, validate for 4 steps
Epoch 1/10
31/31 [==============================] - 11s 352ms/step - loss: -51.9861 - accuracy: 0.0950 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 2/10
31/31 [==============================] - 10s 335ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 3/10
31/31 [==============================] - 10s 334ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 4/10
31/31 [==============================] - 11s 352ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 5/10
31/31 [==============================] - 10s 330ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 6/10
31/31 [==============================] - 10s 331ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 7/10
31/31 [==============================] - 10s 330ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 8/10
31/31 [==============================] - 11s 351ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 9/10
31/31 [==============================] - 11s 355ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
Epoch 10/10
31/31 [==============================] - 11s 364ms/step - loss: -54.3329 - accuracy: 0.0942 - val_loss: -62.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0833
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are doing, it's looks like you are performing a multi-label classification using `Sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy`, which, as the name suggests allows to do a binary classification, with only 2 labels.

In order to have a working model, you have to change your binary model to a multi class one :

- Change your last Dense layer to : `classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=NB_CLASS, activation='softmax'))`
- Change your loss to be : `classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`
- Change your dataflow to be :

```py
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'train', target_size=(64, 64), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'test', target_size=(64, 64), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
```

Keep me in touch !

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do to classify multiple classes. The problem was that every tutorial I found were import MNIST and not from folders...

Comment: Have you try what i recommended to you ? It's should works for you

Comment: Updated git I'm doing a test...seems to work! https://github.com/marcusdiy/testai/blob/master/train.py Gonna try to make it run for a while

Comment: Btw I'm using tensorflow 2 so instead of Dense(output_dim=NB_CLASS, activation='softmax') I'm using Dense(NB_CLASS, activation='softmax') is that right?

Comment: Yes yes sure, i just copied your line from test-keras.py, so adpat it as you want. You only need NB_CLASS neurones and softmax activation ;)

Comment: Seem to be working: https://github.com/marcusdiy/testai/blob/master/train_graph.JPG

Comment: Glad to have helped you ;)